# Difference between consecutive rows in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I would like to get the difference between 2 consecutive rows in the MySql. I am trying to resolve, but no luck. Here is the data in the image

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/keIdU.png]

I need a difference between rows of "Data2" column and results into "Diff" column.

Thanks for your kind attention and much appreciated for your help.

-Ram

Comment: What are your expected results from your given screenshot?

Comment: Are these all your columns? Is there a primary key?

Comment: Expected results is difference of "Data2" Column result of (558-536),(578-558) and so on. Primary key is application_id

Comment: Your primary key cannot be `application_id` -- it repeats -- a primary key must be unique...

Comment: Ram: Please stick to posting data in _SO_ specified format. @sgeddes has updated your data (which was in scrambled text) to image which is also not the best way to post a question. Learn more about [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

If the table have an auto incremental column 'id', We can order by id and identify the next row value and subtract it

```
SELECT t1.*, t1.Data2-(SELECT t2.Data2 FROM  `table_name`  t2 WHERE t2.id > t1.id LIMIT 1 ) AS difference
FROM `table_name`  t1
ORDER BY t1.id
```

to subtract from next row value

```
SELECT t1.*, t1.Data2-(SELECT t2.Data2 FROM  `table_name`  t2 WHERE t2.id < t1.id ORDER BY id DESC  LIMIT 1 ) AS difference
FROM `table_name`  t1
ORDER BY t1.id
```

Comment: Tried it. but results are not expected. Thanks for your support.

Comment: still no luck. Thanks again

Comment: my answer will work only if the table have auto incremental column, here it is column  'id' in my example

Comment: @santhy as you know that id is not auto increment,so why don't you use row_number instead of id.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have a unique column in your table, you can achieve this by including a bind variable [`@rn` & `@rn1`] which adds a *unique number sequentially* to every row in the table.

Try this:

```
SELECT tab1.application_id, tab1.fiscal_year, tab1.data1, coalesce(cast(tab1.data2 as signed) - 
                cast(tab2.data2 as signed), tab1.data2) as diff
  FROM 
      (SELECT b.application_id, @rn1:=@rn1+1 AS rank, b.fiscal_year, b.data1, b.data2
         FROM your_table b, (SELECT @rn1:=0) t1) as tab1,
      (SELECT a.application_id, @rn:=@rn+1 AS rank, a.fiscal_year, a.data1, a.data2
         FROM your_table a, (SELECT @rn:=0) t2) as tab2
 WHERE tab1.rank = tab2.rank + 1;
```